# HTML Beautify Settings in Brackets

Tags: settings, adobe-brackets, js-beautify

I understand that the [Brackets Beautify](https://github.com/drewhamlett/brackets-beautify) extension is based on [JS Beautify](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify), and that I have a suite of preference settings available because of that, but I have no idea of how to alter them through the Brackets settings.json file. Does anyone have any idea?

Here are my current settings:

```
   {
        "debug.showErrorsInStatusBar": false,
        "linting.collapsed": true,
        "wordWrap": false,
        "me.drewh.jsbeautify.on_save": false,
        "styleActiveLine": true,
        "themes.theme": "explicit-brackets-style",
        "fonts.fontSize": "12px"
    }
```

I'm assuming I just need to add new "me.drewh.jsbeautify" lines, but that doesn't seem to work...

I'm specifically looking at HTML settings, BTW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the original [library](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) the extension uses a `.jsbeautifyrc` file for the settings.

It should work if you create such a file in your project root with content like this:

```
{
    "eol": "\n",
    "end_with_newline": true,
    "preserve_newlines": true,
    "max_preserve_newlines": 10,
    "indent_inner_html": false,
    "brace_style": "collapse",
    "indent_scripts": "normal",
    "wrap_line_length": 0,
    "wrap_attributes": "auto"
}
```

---

Additionally, I can only recommend you to have a look at my [fork](https://github.com/Hirse/brackets-beautify) of that extension as it allows [more detailed settings](https://github.com/Hirse/brackets-beautify#beautifier-options).

Comment: .jsbeautifyrc is the full name of the file required rather than just the extension